# extract the last repetitive section of a txt file

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a very big .txt file which contains multiple repetitive sections with the same format but different values. I would like to extract the last repetition and store it into a .csv file.

I have successfully extracted all three repetition and do not know how to proceed. Potentially a script could help but I do not have the logic behind it since I am still a beginner in shell scripting.

The expected result would only contain the last repetition of the series.
The extraction codes:

```
sed -ne '/Summary of Natural Population Analysis:/,/* Total * /p'
```

What I have now:

**Summary of Natural Population Analysis:**

```
                                   Natural Population 
            Natural  -----------------------------------------------
Atom  No    Charge         Core      Valence    Rydberg      Total
```

---

```
  P    1   -0.00730      9.99875     4.96888    0.03967    15.00730
  H    2    0.00243      0.00000     0.99263    0.00493     0.99757
  H    3    0.00243      0.00000     0.99263    0.00493     0.99757
  H    4    0.00243      0.00000     0.99263    0.00493     0.99757
```

=======================================================================
   * Total *    0.00000      9.99875     7.94678    0.05447    18.00000

Summary of Natural Population Analysis:

```
                                   Natural Population 
            Natural  -----------------------------------------------
Atom  No    Charge         Core      Valence    Rydberg      Total
```

---

```
  P    1    0.03819      9.99894     4.93544    0.02743    14.96181
  H    2   -0.01273      0.00000     1.00784    0.00489     1.01273
  H    3   -0.01273      0.00000     1.00784    0.00489     1.01273
  H    4   -0.01273      0.00000     1.00784    0.00489     1.01273
```

=======================================================================
   * Total *    0.00000      9.99894     7.95896    0.04210    18.00000

Summary of Natural Population Analysis:

```
                                   Natural Population 
            Natural  -----------------------------------------------
Atom  No    Charge         Core      Valence    Rydberg      Total
```

---

```
  P    1    0.03819      9.99894     4.93544    0.02743    14.96181
  H    2   -0.01273      0.00000     1.00784    0.00489     1.01273
  H    3   -0.01273      0.00000     1.00784    0.00489     1.01273
  H    4   -0.01273      0.00000     1.00784    0.00489     1.01273
```

=======================================================================
   * Total *    0.00000      9.99894     7.95896    0.04210    18.00000

What I would like to have: 
just

**Summary of Natural Population Analysis:**

```
                                   Natural Population 
            Natural  -----------------------------------------------
Atom  No    Charge         Core      Valence    Rydberg      Total
```

---

```
  P    1    0.03819      9.99894     4.93544    0.02743    14.96181
  H    2   -0.01273      0.00000     1.00784    0.00489     1.01273
  H    3   -0.01273      0.00000     1.00784    0.00489     1.01273
  H    4   -0.01273      0.00000     1.00784    0.00489     1.01273
```

=======================================================================
   * Total *    0.00000      9.99894     7.95896    0.04210    18.00000

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to make it look nice.

Comment: Maybe something based on `sed -n '/^Summary of Natural Population Analysis:$/, // p'`? Actually on second thought `awk` or `perl` would probably be a better tool for this.

Comment: Do sections have a constant number of lines?

Comment: Not a lot response? We are waiting for some text here that we can copy-paste and test, not a picture. Tell us how you extracted the sections, than we know what keywords we can search  for. Pleasse edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not stuck with only sed, I would simply use a unix pipe and add the tail -1 command to it, such as

```
sed 'mysed program' | tail -1
```

You could then store that in the csv file with

```
sed 'mysed program' | tail -1 > my.csv
```